# Spring boot Classnotfoundexception : org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I get the following exception while running the application.

Seems like I am missing a dependency which spring boot needs but not sure which one since I seem to have all of the dependencies.
I thought the spring boot parent dependency would have got all the dependencies needed to start a basic app.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.<clinit>(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.getRepositoryConfigurationExtension(JpaRepositoriesAutoConfigureRegistrar.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:60)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.relay</groupId>
    <artifactId>trestos</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>structure</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>structure</name>

  <properties>
    <main.basedir>..</main.basedir>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You are using your own parent, not Spring Boot. Does your own parent have Spring Boot as parent?

Comment: @dunni yes my parent does have the spring boot parent

Comment: You may have a corrupted jar in your Maven cache. Try deleting it and running you app again